# Changing between two .properties with a same template in FreeMarker

Tags: templates, freemarker, properties-file

I am new to FreeMarker, and what I would like to accomplish is switch between different properties using the same template file, in order to send e-mails in different languages.

My default properties file is messages.properties, and the second file (non-default) I would like to use is messages_fr.properties.

A template file is template.ftl

The code I have is:

```
Map<String, Object> content = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    content.put(I18N, i18nService);
    content.put("someText", "a text";
    content.put("language", language);

    String setBodyTextMessage = commonService.getProcessedTemplate("template.ftl", content);
```

What I am struggling to find out is how to do the same thing as in the code I provided, but by using the messages_fr.properties without changing the configuration file (I would like to make the switch within the Java code).  Furthermore, setting a different locale will not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data-model there, called `content`. You put into that whatever you want, with Java code. Each template processing can use its own data-model. So I'm not sure where do you stuck.

Or, you can create a `ResourceBundle` and put that into the data-model (even as shared variable on the `Configuration`-level), and then set the `locale` setting for that single request (not in the shared `Configuration` object).  To do that, instead of `Configuration.getTemplate` use `Template.createProcessingEnvironment`. In the returned `freemarker.core.Environment` you can set the locale (and other settings), and then call `Environment.process` to generate the output.

Comment: Setting a locale will not work., I have to specify/change .properties file directly and use the same ftl. I am very new to FreeMarker (since yesterday) so that too might be a problem.  Would there be a code example ? What I want to do is, if language is French, process template T with content file F, and if language is english, process template T with a separate content file E.

Comment: Then my first paragraph applies, unless I miss something. That is, put a different `Properties` object into the data-model (which is the `content` object in your case) depending on the locale. The data-model is dynamically built by the Java code, right? That's how it normally goes. The data-model depends on runtime conditions, and the template remains that same.